# Index into a List without using indexing

Tags: python, pytorch, jit, torchvision

I have a [list of modules](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html#torch.nn.ModuleList) into which I want to index using another index list

```py
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as T

transforms = torch.nn.ModuleList([T.ColorJitter(), T.ColorJitter()])
order = [1,0]
```

[I cannot do `transforms[order[0]]`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16123). But, I can iterate over the ModuleList: `for t in transforms:` and `for i,t in enumerate(transforms):` work

How to efficiently index into the ModuleList just by using iteration or enumeration?

I've tried the following but they don't work

- ```py
  # Permute/Change ordering of the ModuleList using a ModuleDict and then iterate the ModuleDict
  permuted_transforms = torch.nn.ModuleDict({order[i]:t for i,t in enumerate(transforms)})
  ```

  gives
  `FrontendError: Cannot instantiate class 'ModuleDict' in a script function`
- ```py
  # Permute/Change ordering of the ModuleList using torch.take
  permuted_transforms = torch.take(self.transforms, order)
  ```

  but torch.take only works on torch.Tensors and not ModuleLists
- ```py
  # Permute/Change ordering of the ModuleList using map
  permuted_transforms = map(self.transforms.__getitem__, order)
  ```
- ```py
  # Permute/Change ordering of the ModuleList using sorted
  permuted_transforms = sorted(self.transforms, key=order.__getitem__)
  ```
- ```py
  # Have 2 for loops work but is extremely ineffecient
  for o in order:
    for i,t in enumerate(transforms):
      if i==o: apply(t)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this should be what you're looking for:

`permuted_transforms = [transforms[i] for i in order]`

Comment: I am not able to index into the ModuleList. So, transforms[i] doesn't work for JIT Scripting in this specific case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).